# Error LINK2019 using OpenNI and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, kinect, openni

I am trying to built a .cpp file using OpenNI in Visual Studio 2012. I am using the code of the SimpleViewer sample (it is included in the OpenNI). When I try to build the .cpp file I got the **error LNK2019** which it seems a problem when the compiler has to link the OpenNI library. What could be wrong?

Errors (55 in total):

```
>  Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__oniShutdown
> referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl
> openni::OpenNI::shutdown(void)"
> (?shutdown@OpenNI@openni@@SAXXZ)  C:\Develop\VisualStudioWorkspace\Projects\My
> programs\OpenNI2_test\OpenNI2_test\Viewer.obj OpenNI2_test
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__oniWaitForAnyStream referenced in function "public: static enum openni::Status __cdecl openni::OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(class openni::VideoStream * *,int,int *,int)" (?waitForAnyStream@OpenNI@openni@@SA?AW4Status@2@PAPAVVideoStream@2@HPAHH@Z) C:\Develop\VisualStudioWorkspace\Projects\My programs\OpenNI2_test\OpenNI2_test\Viewer.obj  OpenNI2_test
```

I followed all the steps described in the [OpenNI website](http://www.openni.org/resources/#.UYKrnrXrweM) to compile a file in Visual Studio: I added all the VCC Directories and the Include and Lib environment variables. I also added OpenNI2.lib in the additional dependencies on the Linker section. I also copied the Redist files in the working directory (the directory where I have the .vcproj).

Comment: There is solution, check this [question][1]
maybe it works in your case!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644191/openni-2-and-visual-studio-2012/15078460#15078460

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue.  The sample projects wouldn't build because I was using OpenNI for x64 but the platform was set to Win32.  Changing to x64 (in the properties dialog at the top) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

OpenNI 2.0 is not mature enough. Most of the libraries, open source codes, examples and wrappers still use OpenNI 1.5. The integration is not easy since OpenNI2 uses the Microsoft official drivers and OpenNI1.x uses the open source drivers. The 32bit version gives less problems than the 64bits but I ended up installing and working the OpenNI 1.5 and the Kinect non-official drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the linking process. You may have wrong link path in the properties of your projects. There is solution, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644191/openni-2-and-visual-studio-2012/15078460#15078460)
maybe it works in your case!