# OpenNI2 Could not initialise library - looking for driver .dlls in project folder?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2012, kinect-sdk, openni

I am trying to get a C++ example to work which uses the OpenNI library for Kinect. I have setup my library as in the correct answer given here for a 32-bit version:

[OpenNI 2 and Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644191/openni-2-and-visual-studio-2012)

However as soon as the code executes:

```
rc = OpenNI::initialize();
if (rc != openni::STATUS_OK)
    throw runtime_error(string("Could not initialize OpenNI: ") +   string(OpenNI::getExtendedError()));
```

I get the error:

```
   Could not initialize OpenNI: Found no files matching (project path) OpenNI2\\Drivers\\*.dll'\n"  const char *
```

The directory OpenNI2\Drivers\ does not exist, and should not in the project (vs2012) folder as far as I am aware?

I have no idea why it would be looking in the project path at all? The kinect divers are installed and openni is downloaded from:

http://structure.io/openni

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the folder here:

```
     C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenNI2\Samples\Bin
```

and copied it to my directory, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Install OpenNI2 from this link: https://structure.io/openni

Add this path as a Environment variable
C:\Program Files\OpenNI2\Samples\Bin

If you don't know how to add path as a variable follow the instruction of this link
https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/