# C++ and Open NI, unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, openni

I am working on a project using Kinect Xbox 360 and Open NI framework. I wrote a simple code for printing Open NI version but it gives me error shown below. 
Any Help? I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Open NI 2

Code:

```
#include "OpenNI.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void main() {
    openni::OpenNI::initialize();
    openni::Version a = openni::OpenNI::getVersion();
    cout << a.build;
 }
```

Error:

```
1>Source.cpp
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__imp__oniInitialize referenced in function "public: static enum 
openni::Status __cdecl openni::OpenNI::initialize(void)" (?
initialize@OpenNI@openni@@SA?AW4Status@2@XZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__imp__oniGetVersion referenced in function "public: static struct 
openni::Version __cdecl openni::OpenNI::getVersion(void)" (?
getVersion@OpenNI@openni@@SA?AUVersion@2@XZ)
```

Comment: how do you link the lib?

Comment: Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644191/openni-2-and-visual-studio-2012 Check your includes.

Comment: @tobi303 I am adding lib through project properties in the C/C++ section, under the "General->Additional Include Directories and -In the Linker section, under the "General" node -> Additional Library Directories

Comment: @Matthias I have tried this solution but no help.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the problem has been resolved :)